# Undefined-method error in ruby syntax

Tags: ruby, syntax, undefined

I don't know why but it keeps saying that prime?(num) method is not defined...
I am trying to make it so that it finds the product of prime numbers between 1 and 20

```
class LCM200        
  def prime?(num)
    if num == 1 then 
        return false
    end
    range = Math.sqrt(num)
    for i in 2..range           
        if num%i == 0
            return false
        end     
        return true
    end
  end
#if __FILE__ == $0
  lcm = 1
  for j in 1..20 do
    if prime?(j)
      lcm *= j
    end
  end       
  puts lcm
#end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because you're running the code inside a class. Inside a class, `prime?` gets defined as an *instance method* of the class, however when you're running the for loop inside the class you're calling `prime?` as though it were a *class method* (aka static method). To fix it, just remove the class declarations:

```
def prime?(num)
    if num == 1 then 
        return false
    end

    range = Math.sqrt(num)
    for i in 2..range

        if num%i == 0
            return false
        end
    end

    # Note: moved return true to here since otherwise it would return
    # true after a single iteration
    return true
end

lcm = 1

for j in 1..20 do
    if prime?(j)
        lcm *= j
    end
end

puts lcm
```

You can also define `prime?` in a more "Ruby-ish" way:

```
def prime? num
  if num == 1
    false
  else
    (2..Math.sqrt(num)).all? { |i| i % num != 0 }
  end
end
```

Documentation for [Enumerable#all?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F)

Comment: So in Ruby, is a method always an instance method when its defined inside a class?

Comment: also what difference does the question mark at the end of "all" method  in this phrase (2..Math.sqrt(num)).all? { |i| i % num != 0 }

Comment: @wayfare: In Ruby, a method is always an instance method, period. Ruby has only one kind of method: instance methods. It doesn't have any other kind of method. In particular, it doesn't have class methods, and it certainly doesn't have static methods or constructors.

Comment: @wayfare: That's what the method is called. The name of the method is `all?`.

Comment: You can write class methods as follows: `def self.prime? num; return true; end;`. You can then call these as: `LCM2000.prime?(num)`. I recommend you use Ruby's built-in `prime?` function I've outlined in my answer, though. No use rewriting functions that are already available.

Comment: Jorg, you are 100% wrong. Ruby **does** have class methods. http://blog.jayfields.com/2007/10/ruby-defining-class-methods.html

Comment: @wayfare: If you define a method as `def self.whatever` it is a class method. The question mark has no significance to Ruby, however by convention any method ending in a question mark means it returns true or false. I added a link to the documentation in my post.

Comment: I tried using self.prime? and it worked. Thank you all for the help!

Comment: @thinkswan: Those aren't class methods, those are instance methods of the class's singleton class. There are no class methods in Ruby. Only instance methods.

Comment: class methods are actually the instance methods of Class.

Comment: +1 for straight up proving me wrong in the terminology battle. :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to define your own `prime?` function. As of Ruby 1.9, you can simply call the `prime?` function of the **mathn** library as follows:

- `require 'mathn'`
- `13.prime?`

An example of this in action:

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'mathn'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> 1.prime?
=> false
irb(main):003:0> 3.prime?
=> true
irb(main):004:0> 11.prime?
=> true
irb(main):005:0> 20.prime?
=> false
```

Comment: Or, similarly, `require 'prime'` followed by `Prime.prime?(x)`.